# Windows 7 vs Windows Server 2008 for a time critical server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7

What are the relevant pros and cons, considerations and differences between Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 while choosing an OS for running time sensitive software (not hosting web)?

What would you choose and why?

Please keep the discussion to facts and refrain from subjective opinions.

Comment: They both share the same code base and I doubt **very much** the time telling ability of either differs. It's not like they're going to do `if(IsClientVersion) { SkewTimeSlightly(); } else { SuperAccurateTime(); }` !

Comment: Specify "time critical". Do you mean "real time"? Then Windows is not a real time OS. In this case you need an OS designed for that purpose. RTLinux for example. And your software must also be designed for real time. So what software is it?

Comment: @Ben: That is not correct. Windows Server OSes do implement different scheduling algorithms than Desktop OSes. Servers prefer background processes than foreground processes.

Comment: For the people voting down - could you please explain your motivation?

Comment: @Jonathan, I didn't cast one of the downvotes, but I strongly suspect they where cast because of how vague your question is.  Please consider updating it to be more specific about what you actually need to do.

Comment: @mailq That's only partly true. It's a matter of default settings, which can be changed. sysdm.cpl->advanced->(Performance)Settings...->Advanced

Comment: Please define "time sensitive software".  Is it real time or what?

Comment: @Jonathan - People are downvoting because, as the FAQ states, this site if for PROFESSIONAL sysadmins, and even considering using W7 in a production environment as a server is considered unprofessional by professional sysadmins.

Answer (score 8):

Windows 7 isn't a Server OS - End.

Comment: Yep. Nailed it.

Comment: oh... but Why ?

Comment: Because... it isn't.